# Using R for analysing relations between administrative borders (neighborhood of polygons) and voting results (or void votes)

Tags: shapefile, r, sf, gam

What would be the relatively simple way to verify if there is a relationship between administrative borders (polygons)  and voting results (like: void votes). This would be used to verify if voting proces was tampered with.

I have: 
 - shp file with administrative borders,
 - data with populations (eligible voters), vote results for particular parties, void votes within these polygons.

So far, by reading various sources I realize it is important to offset for the population in various  polygons and to account for neighboring polygons.

I am wondering what package and what model should be used for such analysis. Would GAM be appropriate? How to account for neighboring polygons as a variable?

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by "a relationship between admin borders and voting results", and what sort of "tampering" you are thinking of.  Do you mean to find if an admin area has voted atypically for its population - eg an area of old people voting big for a typical young-person's party? This is currently a broad question because the best answer as it stands is probably "formulate and fit a statistical model and look for the outliers".

Comment: @Spacedman I admit I am not very knowlegable on that. I admit I would like to account for differences in population (offset?) and neighbourhood (results may depend on regional traditions, historical conditions). And then perhaps indeed I should look at differences in outliers betw the polygons. What kind of regression would be best? Do you perhaps know an example, a tutorial on how to do it? I imagine it can be related to looking for irregularities in spread of epidemics.